# Use Apache remote IP, but require proxy IP to be in range

Tags: apache-2.4, cloudflare

I put my locally hosted sites behind Cloudflare for an added layer of performance.

To restore the original connecting IP, I use `mod_remoteip`, set up with all of Cloudflare's IP ranges.

I also want to set up a site purely for access through Cloudflare Access, restricting access to anyone attempting to connect bypassing Cloudflare Access.

I've read online that you can do this with rules such as `Require ip xx.xx.xx.xx/24` (etc), but these only work in my situation if I am checking against the original proxy IP, but this has already been overwritten by `mod_remoteip`.

Is there any way to enforce the original proxy IP address or require that the request has had the IP rewritten, or anything of the sort that would do what I need?

Answer (score 0):

Simply set up some form of IP-based access control outside of Apache, in a firewall or security group or similar. Allow only the CloudFlare IP-ranges https://www.cloudflare.com/ips/ to access your web server ports and you won’t have detect any requests that by-bass cloud flare in Apache.

More complex Apache only :

Ensure that only requests from CloudFlare are parsed by mod_remoteip :

mod_remoteip  offers the [`RemoteIPTrustedProxyList`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_remoteip.html#remoteiptrustedproxylist) where you can easily load the text version of the list of CloudFlare IP’s

Once you have ensured that mod__remoteip only activates for CloudFlare IP’s you can maybe use the following tidbit hidden in the documentation  :

> The underlying client IP of the connection is available in the %{c}a format string.

And then potentially  base an access control on the presence of that format string. Untested:

```
<If "! %{c}a}”>

    Require all denied
</If>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried out your second solution, as it seemed it'd be easier to implement. I added to one of my `<VirtualHost>` entries, but it complained that `Variable 'c' does not exist.`. Any ideas why this might be?